# how to use transaction like process in myisam in mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, myisam

I am creating an commerce website and i am stuck in a database problem i am storing customer orders please tell me which is better MYISAM or Innodb i have to use transaction like feature in customer order table and i personally prefer myisam because it is much faster than innodb and it also supports full-text searching is there any way to use transaction like rollback feature in myisam so that if anything goes wrong table will be rollback to its previous state how to do that without any external library or any other server side access and i have to use MYSQL

Comment: Always use InnoDB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492771/should-i-use-myisam-or-innodb-tables-for-my-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

I would use innodb because it supports transactions. It is not slower than myisam on selects, and supports fulltext searches from mysql v5.6. It is obviously slower on modifiations, since it uses transactions.

Myisam does not support transactions and I don't think it ever will. You have innodb for that purpose.

Comment: so is there any way to get back to old state in myisam when query fails

Comment: just like rollback do in innodb

Comment: Just like rollback in innodb is not possible in myisam, since rollback requires the concept of transactions. You have to manually undo any changes.